# Android Emulator is Force Closing

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

My Android Emulator is force quitting my program every time I try to run it. I have no idea why, please help me!

```
public class AsteroidsToo extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     new AsteroidWorld(3).bigBang(this);
    }
```

}

Here is the LogCat errors:

```
07-02 17:27:54.873: WARN/dalvikvm(332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{foo.AsteroidsToo/foo.AsteroidsToo.AsteroidsToo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:369)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.image.FromFile.<init>(FromFile.java:25)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at foo.AsteroidsToo.Ship.<init>(AsteroidsToo.java:75)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at foo.AsteroidsToo.AsteroidWorld.<init>(AsteroidsToo.java:196)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at foo.AsteroidsToo.AsteroidsToo.onCreate(AsteroidsToo.java:13)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-02 17:27:54.893: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332):     ... 11 more
07-02 17:27:54.923: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity foo.AsteroidsToo/.AsteroidsToo
07-02 17:27:55.433: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45053848 foo.AsteroidsToo/.AsteroidsToo}
07-02 17:28:03.173: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f2b9d8
07-02 17:28:06.287: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45053848 foo.AsteroidsToo/.AsteroidsToo}
```

Here is the Code for my constructor:

```
/**Represents the World*/
class AsteroidWorld extends VoidWorld{
    Ship sh;
    ArrayList<Bullet> b;
    ArrayList<Asteroids> a;
    int score;
    int HighScore;
    State state;
    int lives;
    double timer;

    public AsteroidWorld(int lives) {
        super();
        this.sh = new Ship(300.0,300.0,0.0,0.0,90.0);
        this.b = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
        this.a = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
        this.score = 0;
        this.HighScore = 0;
        this.timer = 3.0;
        this.state = new Lose();
        this.lives = lives;
```

I also get an error saying:

> [2011-07-02 20:08:08 - Emulator]
>   2011-07-02 20:08:08.156
>   emulator[14734:903] Warning once: This
>   application, or a library it uses, is
>   using NSQuickDrawView, which has been
>   deprecated. Apps should cease use of
>   QuickDraw and move to Quartz

Here is my ship constructor

```
/**Represents the Ship in the game*/
class Ship extends FloatObject{
Image SpaceShip = new FromFile("spaceship.png");
double angle;
double speed = 2;
```

Comment: It would really help us help you if you made your code more readable, i.e. fix your code tags.

Comment: Seems like you have a NPE in the  AstroidWorld constructor, please paste relevant code.

Comment: I updated the post, hopefully now it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I think showing the Ship constructor would be even more useful than the AsteroidWorld constructor. It appears that, in AsteroidWorld, you create a Ship; in this Ship's constructor you try to create an image from a file - the image is represented by a FromFile object and that object's constructor is where the exception is being thrown. In the image.FromFile, it tries to put a value into a HashTable but the value is null.

Comment: That's not the Ship's constructor. The constructor is the method that is named after the object.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, in the Ship's constructor, which you are not showing, the line in that where you create a new instance of FromFile, you are passing a null value to the FromFile's constructor. FromFile's constructor expects a String. You might even be attempting to pass a String to it, but whatever it is getting there is probably actually null.

FromFile's constructor is putting a value into a HashTable, and that value is null instead of what it is expecting. That's all I can gather from not being able to see everything necessary here.

Comment: Where do I put the .png files within the project? I edited the post so you can see my ship constructor.